# Get a part of the second group

Tags: regex

I'm having some difficulties with regex.

Here is an example of the string on which I'm doing regex:

```
This is some useless information (first;second;third;fourth;fifth;sixth) (seventh;eigth;ninth;tenth)
```

I am looking for a regex that will allows me to pick only one of the word in parenthesis, like 'ninth'. The word I need to pick depends on where I'm in my program, so I will just adapt the regex once I will know how to write it

The best I have found for the moment is : `(?<=\()([^]]+?)(?=\)).*?` 
That allows me to match the whole content of the group between parenthesis.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Which language/regex engine? Why not just use the regex you already have and split on `;`? Also, perhaps you meant to have the pattern `(?<=\()([^)]+)(?=\))` instead?

Comment: In some languages you can use something like `(?<=\(|\G(?!\A);)([^);]+)`, otherwise, I'd just stick to my previous comment, merging the arrays and getting the nth item.

Comment: 1) Get all substrings inside parentheses, 2) split their contents with a regex 3) use the resulting list further in the program.

Comment: @ctwheels i'm using python, and you're right I meant  `(?<=\()([^)]+)(?=\))`

Answer (score 2):

If the need is to match the contents between parenthesis given a variable
input parameter it can be done like this :

`(?<=\()(?:(?![()]).)*?(?<=[(;])(ninth)(?=[);])(?:(?![()]).)*(?=\))`

It is dynamically constructed by joining the three parts.

`(?<=\()(?:(?![()]).)*?(?<=[(;])(` + ***variable*** + `)(?=[);])(?:(?![()]).)*(?=\))`

https://regex101.com/r/6yxQyp/1

Where the variable is captured in group 1 if needed.

Comment: A lot of lookarounds :) but pretty nice solution +1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I finally find a regex that allows me to get the value I wanted.

To reuse my example :

```
This is some useless information (first;second;third;fourth;fifth;sixth) (seventh;eigth;ninth;tenth)
```

The worlds 'first' and 'seventh' will always be there so if i want to get the value of second i will use :

```
\(first;(\w+)
```

to get ninth's value i will use :

```
\(seventh;\w+;(\w+)
```

Hope this will help someone else !

Have a good day :)